# Android MediaPlayer Streaming Error: 100: MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED

Tags: android, stream, android-mediaplayer, media

I've developed an app which takes an advantage of the native Android's MediaPlayer. The source code of my class making use of Media Player is below.

The problem is that only on some devices after some miliseconds of playback (I hear only voice, the screen remains black) I keep getting `error(100,0)` which according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) says

> `public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED`
>
> Media server died. In this case, the application must release the MediaPlayer object and instantiate a new one.

On forums I've found out that I need to reset the player every time I get it... but I get it after just a short moment and then it dies forever. I cannot reset the player every second since playback is useless. I cannot get why some devices have this problem and others not. The one that I know has Android OS > 4.0.

Of course, first `init()` and then `showVideo()` are getting called. The last `onError` with code 100 is then called. What's a potential solution to make the streams run continuously and not break?

```
public class NativePlayer extends Player implements OnBufferingUpdateListener,
        OnCompletionListener, OnErrorListener, OnInfoListener {

    private VideoView videoview;
    private PlayerListener listener;
    private MainActivity context;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NativePlayer.class);

    @Override
    public void init(MainActivity activity) {
        this.videoview = (VideoView) activity.findViewById(R.id.video);
        context = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void showVideo(final String url, final PlayerListener _listener) {
        listener = _listener;
        videoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        try {
            Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error playing video", e);
            listener.onVideoError();
            return;
        }

        videoview.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        videoview.setOnErrorListener(this);
        videoview.requestFocus();

        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoview.start();
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onVideoStarted();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        stop();
    }

    private void stop() {
        if (videoview == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (videoview.isPlaying()) {
            videoview.stopPlayback();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        stop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onVideoError();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onInfo(what, extra);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onBufferingUpdate(percent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem (error 100, mediaplayer died, etc.).
I resolve it by using .stopPlayback(), and starting stream again.
Below is my part of code:

```
private void startWatchVideo(final string video_link) {
        videoViewVA.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoViewVA.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video_link));
        videoViewVA.requestFocus();
        videoViewVA.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer media) {
                media.start();
            }
        });

        videoViewVA.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer media, int what, int extra) {
                if (what == 100)
                {
                    videoViewVA.stopPlayback();
                    startWatchVideo(video_link);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

On practice it looks like video is just slows down

Comment: thanks for your feedback :) sorry to say but i've got a Huawei device here which says error 100 and nothing helps it to play HLS, just switching to an alternative player fixed the problem :(

Comment: If the solution does not work and restarting the video leads to a 100 again, you'll get into a loop of starting and stopping the video.

Comment: @Kim i added retry count i tried 2 times if again fails i showed error message.

Comment: @basta what alternative player? can you please elaborate?